# Windows - copying files based on existence of other files

Tags: powershell, batch, script

I've a folder with subfolders of photos in jpg format.
The files are arranged as follows:

```
Z:\jpgs\Armouries\fb\IMG_1286.jpg
Z:\jpgs\Balloon\fb\IMG_1129.jpg
Z:\jpgs\Party\fb\P5060092.jpg
```

etc...
There are a couple of hundreds of these.

I also have another folder with subfolders as follows:

```
z:\masters\Armouries\IMG_1286.RAW
z:\masters\Balloon\IMG_1129.DNG
z:\masters\Party\P5060092.CR2
```

etc...
Again there are several hundreds of these folder.

What I want to do is copy the files from the 'masters'tree to a new folder ONLY if the same filename exists in the 'jpgs' tree. Not all files in the masters tree have a corresponding jpg - these files would be ignored.

Hope I've explained that clearly...any pointers?

Comment: I see you are a new user to the site - welcome! You explained your question well. This site is geared around questions containing specific technical questions. Your problem is clear, but we like to see that you've made an attempt to resolve it yourself, and need help with a technical detail. Future questions you post will be better answered when you include the code you've written, where the code is giving you problems, and any error messages you may have seen.

Comment: Yes point taken...my problem was I was getting nowehere near :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$jpgs = "C:\jpgs"
$masters = "C:\masters"
$destination = "C:\new"

# store all BaseNames and necessary parent folders to match in an array
$namesToMatch = @()
gci $jpgs -File -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName -Uniq | % {
    # BaseName and parent folder(s) (eg "\Armouries\IMG_1286")
    $namesToMatch += (($_ -split "\\jpgs")[-1] -split "\.")[0]
}

# evaluate each file we might need to copy
gci $masters -File -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName -Uniq | % {

    # BaseName and parent folder(s) (eg "\Armouries\IMG_1286")
    $name = (($_ -split "\\masters")[-1] -split "\.")[0]
    # path + Fullname, in the "new" folder structure (eg "C:\new\Armouries\IMG_1286.jpg")
    $desiredDestination = $_ -replace "masters","new"
    # path in the "new" folder structure with no file name (eg "C:\new\Armouries")
    $desiredDestination_noFile = $desiredDestination.Substring(0,$desiredDestination.LastIndexOf("\"))

    # if we should copy this file
    if($name -in $namesToMatch) {

        # create the parent directories if needed
        if(!(Test-Path -Path $desiredDestination_noFile)) {
            md -force $desiredDestination_noFile | Out-File null
        }

        # copy the file
        cp $_ $desiredDestination

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, slight problem in that it only seems to copy the folders not the files in them. So in my example I get the folders "Balloon, Party, Armouries created in "new" but they are empty folder.

Comment: I didn't notice the subfolders. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Cheers for the update. Almost there; the script is copying from 'masters' to 'new' but only the jpg files in 'masters' not the files with the same basename but different extension. So in the example it will copy IMG_1286.jpg but not IMG_1286.raw.

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes the same conventions as in the question, i.e. masters are in `z:\masters` and JPGs are in `z:\jpgs`. The destination folder is assumed to be `z:\dest`.

#### Short answer

```
dir -File -Recurse z:\masters\ | % { if (dir -Recurse  "z:\jpgs\$($_.BaseName).jpg") { mkdir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $($_.Directory -replace "\\masters\\", "\dest\"); cp $_.FullName $($_.FullName -replace "\\masters\\", "\dest\")} }
```

Short explanation: for each file in `z:\masters` or one of its direct and indirect subdirectories, it checks whether any direct or indirect subdirectory of `z:\jpgs` contains a JPG file with same base name, and if so, copies the master file to the destination folder after creating the parent directories if necessary.

You can test [this solution online](https://tio.run/##pZNvb9owEMbf51Ocok4pEkkAaRXdXkG7sk5ahtikvuxMcgFPjh3Zjhjq@tnZxfwLdIxqexMlvt/dc8@dU6oFajNHIVYJLsJ7iwWE35Ylwi3XmFqllxB@0FrpQWq5kvCVC5RWLG@UtFxWCFFs0di4YMZSpXigC1VpjqZ9HBkyIZSSL87HTNvl7jSrH/ALvlQ2TCohvPrljkRPCsX3n0eP3V7/KpoMHk7iG/U13O1dR7fJ6CTsWorHbztXnc51L7qZ9F6Ddvt9h3r/N8kf5azpLp@2DyJbI8fn60by6d9m96L0fnYU@jO@19vP7iS8bWI/uxpdPWhuMfyojAV/iLnSCPgT04p8z8DOEVJVFExmbQjW1QI6kZZxad753izlEE4I1wahqUlW38AdGU1YgZ6Xcb0J7@jDZTn@CXgOl47dUuA3PVxcXjxGQ2awrtqqDfgtyvrHpbpqDVhjKViK4O9ukN@mD3ft/dZ7SEughK2pdfru60z2Mzw3t@81x/5dDnJKODN3VykAbiDVyCxmQNFX7cJlHi3kUD9RllPrc7Vw0nmdG5z9mwJYMANSWeqi5NSQVRBs2pxiyirqg8rRjeI1RpTWaEols9rjp/HICUX@avUb). (Note: the online version uses `/` as the path separator instead of `\` because it runs on Linux, and `New-Item -Type Directory` instead of `mkdir` because of a limitation of the online execution environment.)

#### With proper indentation and aliases expanded

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse z:\masters\ | ForEach-Object {
    if (Get-ChildItem -Recurse  "z:\jpgs\$($_.BaseName).jpg") {
        mkdir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $($_.Directory -replace "\\masters\\", "\dest\")
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $($_.FullName -replace "\\masters\\", "\dest\")
    }
}
```

#### Detailed explanation

- `dir -File -Recurse z:\masters\` lists all files in `z:\masters` and its subdirectories (`-Recurse`). `dir` is an alias for [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem)
- `%` is an alias for [ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object). It executes a script block (enclosed in braces `{}`) for each object in the pipeline.
- `$_` is the [current object in the pipeline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) (i.e. one of the master files).
- `dir -Recurse  "z:\jpgs\$($_.BaseName).jpg"` returns all files in the `z:\jpgs` directory and its subdirectories that have the same base name as the current master file (`$_.BaseName`) and a `.jpg` extension. It returns `$null` if there are none, which is then converted to `$false` when it is evaluated as the condition of the `if` statement.
- `$_.FullName -replace "\\masters\\", "\dest\"` is the full path of the destination file: it is the full path of the master file (`$_.FullName`) where `\masters\` is replaced with `\dest\` by using the [-replace operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators). This is used to have the same directory structure in `\dest` as in `\masters`.
- `mkdir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $($_.Directory -replace "\\masters\\", "\dest\")` creates the parent folders of the destination file. This step is required because  `Copy-Item` does not currently allow (as of PowerShell 6.1) to create parent directories if necessary and fails when they are missing. The `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`parameter prevents the `mkdir` command from failing if the parent directories already exist.
- `Copy-Item $_.FullName $($_.FullName -replace "\\masters\\", "\dest\")` copies the master file to the destination folder.

#### Remarks

In the `$_.FullName -replace "\\masters\\", "\dest\"` expression, backslashes (`\`) are doubled in the first parameter to `-replace` but not in the second. This is because the first parameter to the [-replace operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) is a *regular expression* in which a backlash is a special character that needs to be escaped, whereas backslash is not a special character in the replacement string (the second parameter).